# DateTimeOffset, not clear understanding

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datetimeoffset

I read a documentation about DateTimeOffset, property DateTime.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

> The DateTime property is not affected by the value of the Offset
>   property. This property returns both the date and the time component
>   of a DateTimeOffset object, which makes it useful for performing
>   DateTimeOffset to DateTime conversion. For example, if the
>   DateTimeOffset object has a date and time value of "1/12/07 4:01pm +
>   7:30", the property returns a date of "1/12/07 4:01pm".

I have +2 GMT timezone and try the following code:

```
    var dateString = "2012-03-01 00:00:00-23:00";
    var birthDay = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
    DateTimeOffset dtOffset = new DateTimeOffset(birthDay);
```

then I look at property DateTime of dtOffset object and see {3/2/2012 1:00:00 AM} value. UtcDateTime has {3/1/2012 11:00:00 PM} value, LocalDateTime has {3/2/2012 1:00:00 AM} value. So, property DateTime of DateTimeOffset instanse has DateTime WITH Offset. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DateTimeOffset really should be called ADateTimeWithAnOffset, because it has two properties -- the DateTime you supply, and the Offset. This makes it useful for conversions, but does NOT convert anything itself.

[From the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...The DateTimeOffset structure includes a DateTime value, together with an Offset property that defines the difference between the current DateTimeOffset instance's date and time and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Your time is interesting, not because of the DateTimeOffset, but because of your initial string format.  As soon as you add the offset to the send of the string, it takes into account your local time offset as well when creating the underlying DateTime.  In my time zone, which is UCT-5, this is what happens...

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse( "2012-03-01"));
3/1/2012 12:00:00 AM

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("2012-03-01  00:00:00-23:00"));
3/1/2012 6:00:00 PM
```

And if you check the Kind property on the underlying DateTime, you'll see that it is Local as soon as you create it from the string with the offset.

Comment: yes, but why I have an affected DateTime in the example above? "dateString" has '2012-03-01' date, why DateTimeOffset converted it affecting with my local time?

Comment: Updated the answer to discuss the time offsets.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you missed is that UtcDateTime and LocalDateTime actually are conversions. So if you reference these two properties, you are asking for converted values. For that reason, the values they got you do not contradict the statement "The DateTime property is not affected by the value of the Offset property."

UtcDateTime converts the DateTime property's value to UTC using the offset (it adds 23 hours to the DateTime part).

LocalDateTime converts the DateTime property's value to YOUR local time according to your Windows TimeZone setting (which must be UTC-1?).